# Why does this bootstrap 4 code not display two images per row on small screen?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

It displays three images on a large screen which is what I want but it only display one image per row on a small window when it should display 2 images.

```
 <div class="container">
  <h2>Pictures of Coffee</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/04LDEYRW59.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/90V03Q5Y60.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/O83SF2RB6D.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/5JVPSVP7EI.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/C5Y10KIIHA.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/YSSFRY5B25.jpg" alt=""></div>

  </div>
```

I thought col-xs-6 would divide into two as 6 is half of 12?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I thought col-xs-6 would divide into two as 6 is half of 12?

There is no `*-xs` in bootstrap 4, just `col-6` is fine.

Check the BS4 grid options [here](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options)

[image]

Comment: To clarify; Bootstrap 4 removed the `-xs` prefix.  It's now just `col-*`, `col-sm-*`, `col-md-*`, and `col-lg-*` where `col-*` replaces `-xs`

Answer (score 1):

That's because the `col-xs-*` class doesn't exist in Bootstrap 4 anymore.

It's just `col-*` now for the smallest screen size.